# Oracle relational model subview by relations

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I've a pretty big oracle db, 50+ tables, load of relations.
The relational model I generated looks (you can imagine..) really scary.

So I'm wondering:

**Is it possible to generate a subview like e.g.**
*"I have this table A and I want the subview to include only tables that have FK's pointing at A"*

I am running Oracle SQL Developer 4.0.3.16, but for the sakes of good, I am willing to install another environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most definitely. Select your 'root' table. Right-click, hit 'select neighbors' Tell it how many levels to go.

With those items selected, right click again, and hit 'create subview from selected.'

There's your subview.

Subviews are great for making large models more manageable for readability, reporting, and searching.

I talk a bit about [subviews here](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2011/11/sql-developer-data-modeler-quick-tip-use-subviews/).

Comment: This is prescisely what I was looking for. Thank you Sir

Answer (score 0):

The `ALL_CONSTRAINTS` table contains all kinds of constraints, including the foreign keys. The constraint type for foreign keys are `'R'` as Referential (or Referenced).

```
SELECT
  A.TABLE_NAME  AS ORIGINATING_TABLE ,
  A.COLUMN_NAME AS ORIGINATING_COLUMN,
  A.CONSTRAINT_NAME                  ,
  C.OWNER                            ,
  C.R_OWNER                          ,
  C_PK.TABLE_NAME AS REFERENCED_TABLE
FROM
  ALL_CONS_COLUMNS A
JOIN ALL_CONSTRAINTS C
ON
  A.OWNER           = C.OWNER AND
  A.CONSTRAINT_NAME = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
JOIN ALL_CONSTRAINTS C_PK
ON
  C.R_OWNER           = C_PK.OWNER AND
  C.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME = C_PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE
  C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'R' AND
  C_PK.TABLE_NAME   = 'AO_563AEE_MEDIA_LINK_ENTITY';
```

Answer (score 0):

In user_constraints you'll find all constraints. There are also the foreign key constraints. You can find the table with:

```
select table_name 
from user_constraints
where constraint_type = 'R'
  and r_constraint_name = 'primary key of A';
```